# Django filter parent objects into child class

Tags: mysql, django

I have a parent class and a child class with extra fields.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    productcode = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    keywords = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        managed = True

class Tent(Product):
    maxcapacity = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    material = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I'm importing my xml data via a third party program (http://community.pentaho.com/projects/data-integration/) into the Product MySQL table. When I run syncdb (or south schemamigrate), I want the Tent table to automatically populate itself with the objects from Product that include the keyword "tent".

Using Django 1.6 and Python 2.7

Comment: The question is kind of unclear. Are you referring: every time insert a Product, automatically create a Tent which will inherit Product? If it is, why don't you use foreign key rather than class level inheritance?

Comment: You're right, I was confused about how Django's ForeignKey field works. I need to use that along with the limit_choices_to argument. The other option I found was to make a custom model manager to change the get_queryset function.

Comment: Okay I set up the foreign key but I'm still a little confused. How do I populate the child model? On the admin page, I can see all the Products, but when I access the Tent model, it's still empty after running syncdb.

Comment: Two things: first, remember to '@' another users when you reply them, so they will be notified about new reply (I didn't notice your reply until I revisit this post); second, for your question, there are many ways to achieve what you want (by the way, I am still confused about what exactly you want). I suggest you update your post with latest version of code and also clarify what is the order of creating Product and Tent. Is there already a Tent instance exist when you creating product, or you want to create a Tent with creation of Tent?

Comment: And two more things:), first, I didn't '@' you because you are post owner. All the comments go to you by default, but you should '@' me; second, I don't think your question has anything to do with MySQL.

Comment: @JerryMeng Sorry, definitely was unclear in my original question. It should make more sense with the edit. Since yesterday, I've figured out that I probably need to write a custom data migrate for south. Or I may just write a python script to parse the xml and update my objects. Thanks for bearing with my noobness.

Comment: No problem man. Your solution sounds OK. If it is just a one time thing, a data migration or even a script will do (generally, data migration is better than script; if you really need script, make it as a management command. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/). If it is not an one time thing, override save or hook post_save signal will all do the job. Good luck~

Comment: @JerryMeng I'll be downloading an xml feed and updating daily. The post_save signal looks very interesting. Thanks again.